# Is this operator continuous?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let
$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 0 & \mbox{if  } x \leq 0 \\
 -3 & \mbox{if } 0<x \leq 1 \\
    1/x & \mbox{if  } x > 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
\\
$$
and let the operator $T(g) = fg$ in the space $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to know if the operator is continuos and how I can get $\|T\|$.

Comment: What are or were your attempts? Pls enrich/edit your post correspondingly!
Btw, $T$ looks rather continuous, and nice norm delimiters like in $\|T\|=3$ are obtained via the command "\|".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $||f||_{\infty} = 3$, we get $||T(g)|| \leq 3||g||$. For $g = I_{[0,1]}$, the indicator function of $[0,1]$, we have equality. Hence $||T|| = 3$.

Comment: This looks what i was looking for. And, what would be $ ker(T) $ ?

Comment: @MiguelNoTeimporta, any function that is $0$ a.e. on the positive real line.